# Jessie Lite: kernel module knfsd.ko is missing

Tags: raspbian

Jessie Lite doesn't provide the `knfsd.ko` kernel module.  So I suppose that I have to compile a new kernel myself.

However, `uname -r` returns `4.4.13-v7+` but `apt-get install linux-source` installs `linux-source-3.16`.

What is the best way to proceed?  I could download the Linux sources from linux.org and compile them myself, but then I have to maintain everything myself.

Edit:

After rebooting the system I came closer.  It seems that searching for `knfsd.ko` isn't sufficient, though advertised everywhere in the internet.

After a reboot `nfs-kernel-server` isn't started automatically at boot time but now I can start it manually.

The reason is that at boot time `nfs-kernel-server` is started before `rpcbind`.  The (ugly) workaround is to add a line

`service nfs-kernel-server restart`

to `rc.local`.

I suspect that I accidentally damaged the init scripts so that rpcbind is is executed too late. Is there a way to recover?

I already removed rpcbind and installed it again but it doesn't help.  Can I repair the init scripts with `update-rc.d` somehow?

Regards, Reinhard